# Induced Spec map for a morphism of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

I have a morphism $f:A\longrightarrow B$ of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.
I have proven, using Zariski's lemma, that the inverse image of a maximal ideal $M \subset B$ is a maximal ideal $f^{-1}(M) \subset A$, hence the induced map $\operatorname{Spec}(f) : \operatorname{MaxSpec}(B) \longrightarrow \operatorname{MaxSpec}(A)$ defined by $\operatorname{Spec}(f)(M) = f^{-1}(M)$ is well-defined, and even continuous for the Zarkiski topology.

Now I need to prove that

> $f$ is surjective $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{Spec}(f)$ is injective

I have proven the implication "$\Longrightarrow$", since I think it's only a matter about set theory.
I am stuck in the other implication. By factoring $f : A \longrightarrow A/\ker(f) \longrightarrow B$, I think I may assume that $f$ is injective, but I don't know how to proceed with that.

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of $\Leftarrow$? Consider $k[x] \subset k[x, x^{-1}]$.

Comment: I can't see why this is a counterexample for the $\Longleftarrow$. I tried to see it through $\mathbb{C}[x] \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ and to compute the MaxSpec of both, I get

$MaxSpec(\mathbb{C}[x]) = \{ (x-a) , a \in \mathbb{C} \}$

$MaxSpec(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)) = \{ (x-a,y-b) , a,b \in \mathbb{C} , and s.t. f(a,b)=0 for all f \in (xy-1) \}$

I can't see why $f^{-1}(M_1) = f^{-1}(M_2) \Longrightarrow M_1 = M_2$.

Comment: Ohh I think I can see it, correct me if I'm wrong:

the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ are essentially of the form $(x-a,y-1/a)$, and so $f^{-1}( (x-a,y-1/a) ) = (x-a)$, so by the knowledge of this point "a" you can recover all the ideal, is that correct?

Comment: Something like that. In my head I'm cheating and using the fact that whenever I localize a ring I get an inclusion of (prime) spectra.

Comment: Notation: It is a very bad idea to denote fg algebras by $X,Y,\dotsc$ because this is the usual name for their spectra. Better choose $R,S,\dotsc$ or $A,B,\dotsc$.